# OpenLayers - How to display selected features as graphic markers?

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, markers

I'm attempting to render a point feature as a graphic.  When that feature is selected I'd like to display a green indicator above the graphic.  It seems backgroundGraphic and externalGraphic are perfect for this...but I can't get it right.

```
    function getStyles()
    {
        var unselectedMarkerOptions = {
            pointRadius : 24,
            strokeWidth : 1,
            fillOpacity : 1,
            graphicHeight : 48,
            graphicWidth : 48,
            externalGraphic : "http://usgvdcalix2:83/openlayers/img/blank.png",
            backgroundWidth : 48,
            backgroundHeight : 48,
            backgroundGraphic : "http://usgvdcalix2:83/openlayers/img/marker-blue.png"
        };


        var selectedMarkerOptions = {
            pointRadius : 24,
            strokeWidth : 1,
            fillOpacity : 1,
            graphicHeight : 8,
            graphicWidth : 8,
            externalGraphic : "http://usgvdcalix2:83/openlayers/img/greendot.png",
            backgroundWidth : 48,
            backgroundHeight : 48,
            backgroundGraphic : "http://usgvdcalix2:83/openlayers/img/marker.png"
        };

        return {
            selected : new ol.Style(ol.Util.applyDefaults(selectedMarkerOptions, ol.Feature.Vector.style["default"])),
            unselected : new ol.Style(ol.Util.applyDefaults(unselectedMarkerOptions, ol.Feature.Vector.style["default"]))
        };
    }
```

I add these styles to a stylemap and associate it with a vector layer but it doesn't behave well:

```
var styles = getStyles ();
var styleMap = new ol.StyleMap({
    "default": styles.unselected,
    "select": styles.selected
});

var featureLayer = new ol.Layer.Vector ( "Features", {
    styleMap : styleMap,
    renderers : ol.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers
} );
```

- It requires a transparent image (blank.png).
- User must click the externalGraphic meaning the 8x8 "greendot.png".
- Setting backgroundGraphicZIndex to a large value to make it a foreground graphic didn't work.

The OL [select-feature-multilayer](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html) example works well.  But I'm looking for a tiny green indicator to show that a feature is selected with the ability to click the feature and toggle the indicator.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option I selected is to listen to the map "click" event and manually test if each marker is contained in the click area:

```
    var olMap = new ol.Map(mapDiv, {
        projection: new ol.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new ol.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        eventListeners: {
            "click": function (evt)
            {
                var delta = 16;
                var ll = olMap.getLonLatFromPixel({ x: evt.xy.x - delta, y: evt.xy.y + delta });
                var ur = olMap.getLonLatFromPixel({ x: evt.xy.x + delta, y: evt.xy.y - delta });
                var extent = new ol.Bounds(ll.lon, ll.lat, ur.lon, ur.lat);
                var features = array.filter(controls.selectFeature.layer.selectedFeatures, function (f)
                {
                    var center = f.geometry.getCentroid();
                    return extent.contains(center.x, center.y);
                });
                array.forEach(features, controls.selectFeature.unselect);
            }
        }
    });
```